# laravel composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

Tags: laravel

Al poner esta instrucción:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

me arroja el siguiente error :

> Warning: require(/home/vagrant/code/laravel_email/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/code/laravel_email/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta el siguiente comando, instalará automáticamente las dependencias necesarias:

```
composer install
```

Y prueba a volver a ejecutar tu comando despues

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas instalar las dependencias de PHP utilizando [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Puedes hacerlo usando el comando `composer install` o `composer update`

Esto debería de descargar e instalar las dependencias que necesitas

Comment: Si el error persiste responde e intentare ayudarte

Comment: hola ya probe con ambos y marca errores aun Fatal error: composerRequireed1eee2acaaa58a03709cae7d26ef504(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/code/basura/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/code/basura/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Answer (score 0):

Como han dicho los anteriores comentarios, este error suele suceder cuando faltan componentes por instalar.

Utiliza

```
composer install
```

Asegúrate de que en el composer.json tienes algo similar a esto

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.4",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.4", <-------------
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
```

Si el la carpeta "guzzlehttp" existe dentro de "vendor", entonces puedes probar:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Este comando recarga el "autoload" de las clases que se han instalado con composer.